# Is setting up jdbc url property through an EntityManager instance re-open the connection

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

Here is my EntitymanagerFactory:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("provider", org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.class);
properties.put("eclipselink.cache.shared.default", "false");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/na");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "UserName");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "Password");
EntityManagerFactory emfForJPAContainer = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit"R, properties);
EntityManager em = emfForJPAContainer.createEntityManager();
em.setProperty("eclipselink.tenant-id","na");
```

Now the following code will save a userAccount to schema "na":

```
em.getTransection().begin();
UserAccount ua = new UserAccount(userName, pass);
em.persist(ua);
em.getTransection().commit();
```

Now the following will save the user account to schema "na_1" with same EntityManager from above:

```
em.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/na_1");
em.getTransection().begin();
UserAccount ua = new UserAccount(userName, pass);
em.persist(ua);
em.getTransection().commit();
```

Now when I set the jdbc url in the runtime like this:

```
 em.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/na_1");
```

Does it re-connect with the database with the na_1 schema?
Is it efficient? Or will it have any bad effects on performence?

Btw I'm using EclipseLink 2.6.1 .

Edited: Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Here goes all class path</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: An EMF controls the datastore connection. An EM simply uses what the EMF gives it.

Comment: Yeap I know that EMF controls the datastore connection. Then while the EMF is first initialize for the first time the schema is "na", then afterwards when I'm setting this em.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/na_1") then the EntityManager is working on schema na_1 although nothing is changed from the EMF. So what is happening there actually?

Comment: Calling that method has absolutely zero guarantee that the JPA provider will support any such property. i.e your code becomes vendor-specific. Many vendors will NOT allow you to change the database in a single EM. In terms of what EclipseLink is doing, look in the code ... gets a new DataSource just for that EM and uses connections from that? There is nothing in the JPA spec to define what happens

Comment: Better to specify what you are trying to accomplish, as what this does really doesn't matter - Changing the database or any portion of the connection makes the data stored in the cache inconsistent.  If you are trying to use specific connections for specific clients, you'll want to turn off the shared cache so that the data isn't inadvertently shared among these client - see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Sessions_(ELUG)#Isolated_Client_Sessions

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are setting same property with same value again so it doesnt make any difference.
Apart from that if you set the property runtime and than you execute "em.getTransection().begin();" than it will use the new property but if after setting property runtime you execute the code:
em.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/na_1");
em.getTransection().begin();

than it will override the runtime property.

Comment: When it is overriding the run time property then will it re-connect with the database for the new schema in the jdbc url?

Comment: It wont actually reconnect. it will connect for once only and That depends on whether your begin transaction get executed before or after this runtime property set.